# NSButton does not show alternative Title since SDK update?

Tags: macos, xcode4.5, nsbutton

### Background Information:

I've recently upgraded from Lion to MountainLion and the newest xCode. The app im working on has deployment target 10.7.

### Problem:

I've a `NSButton` setup in the Interfacebuilder with **Title: "Start"** and **Alternate: "Stop"**. In the buttons `IBAction` I check the state of the application (BOOL isRunning) and change the state every time the button is pressed like this:

```
[startStopButton setState:[appDelegate.dataController appIsRunning]];
```

Everything worked fine. **Since I upgraded to the new xCode the button does not change the title anymore.**

### Things I already tried out:

- Checked all the connections between IBAction and IBOutlet according
  this button. Reset everything up. Did not help.
- Created a new NSButton tried the same. Did not work.
- Setting the titles via code: Did not work.

  ```
  [startStopButton setTitle:@"Start"];
  [startStopButton setAlternateTitle:@"Stop"];
  ```
- Thought it may have been a problem with the boolean value. So I
  checked if the button is not in mixed mode. Then hardcoded statechanges
  with 1 and 0 from type int. No change at all.
- Somehow when I use `[startStopButton setTitle:@"TEST"]` and then change the state, it changes the state ONCE to alternate but not back anymore. The "TEST" String is never seen on the button also...
- I logged the value of `[appDelegate.dataController appIsRunning]` and
  it returns the correct values.

I have no clue how to solve this. Everything worked fine, I changed nothing and it doesn't make any sense to me. Has anybody encountered a equivalent problem?

Comment: BTW 'state' is not a BOOL, it's "NSOffState", "NSOnState", ...

Comment: ...which I stated in my question. ;-) But thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Interface Builder, change the button type to "Toggle".
I'm not sure of the reason, but it appears that alternate title does not work for "Momentary" and "Push" button types.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. I'll check it out tonight and report if it worked!

Comment: This has been the mistake! Thanks a lot!